# Show that for $M=S^2$, $L$ is a plus or minus the identity.

Tags: differential-geometry

> Show that for $M=S^2$, the Weingarten map $L$ is a plus or minus the identity by computing the $L_{ik}$ in a coordinate patch and raising an index.

We know $L(x_k)=\Sigma {L_k}^l x_l$ and ${L_k}^k = \Sigma L_{ik} g^{il}$

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

So pick some nice coordinate patches covering $S^2$ and work through them.

For example. let's do the stereographic projection from north pole:
$$
\mathbf{X}(u,v)=\left(\frac{2u}{u^2+v^2+1}, \frac{2v}{u^2+v^2+1}, \frac{u^2+v^2-1}{u^2+v^2+1}\right).
$$
The metric is
$$
\left(\frac{2}{u^2+v^2+1}\right)^2(du^2+dv^2)
$$
and with $\mathbf{n}=\mathbf{X}$, by explicit computation yields
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{n}\cdot\mathbf{X}_{uu}=\mathbf{n}\cdot\mathbf{X}_{vv}&=-\frac{4}{(u^2+v^2+1)^2},\\
\mathbf{n}\cdot\mathbf{X}_{uv}&=0.
\end{align*}
giving $L$ as desired.